# Controlling a minecraft server with python

Tags: python-3.x, server, minecraft, servermanager

I've searched a lot for this and have not yet found a definitive solution. The closest thing I've found is this:

```
import shutil
from os.path import join
import os
import time
import sys

minecraft_dir = ('server diectory')
world_dir = ('server world driectory')

def server_command(cmd):
    os.system('screen -S  -X stuff "{}\015"'.format(cmd))

on = "1"

while True:
    command=input()
    command=command.lower()
    if on == "1":
        if command==("start"):
            os.chdir(minecraft_dir)
            os.system('"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar nogui java')
            print("Server started.")
            on = "0"
    else:
        server_command(command)
```

When I launch this program and type 'start' the CMD flashes up and closes instantly. Instead I want the CMD to stay open with the minecraft sever running from it. I'm not sure why this happens or what the problem is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I have edited this to my needs (such as removing a backup script that was unnecessary) but it didn't work before. The original link is: https://github.com/tschuy/minecraft-server-control

Comment: why do you need it in python? Generally, minecraft servers are written in Java, and the server is runned straight from it with a .bat or .sh file

Comment: Well, it's the only programming I know how to use. I also want to be able to e-mail my PC to execute a command or start the server so I can control it remotely.

Answer (score 7):

`os.system` will simply run the command then return to your python script with no way to further communicate with it.

On the other hand using `subprocess.Popen` gives you access to the process while it runs, including writing to it's `.stdin` which is how you send data to the server:

```
def server_command(cmd):
    process.stdin.write(cmd+"\n") #just write the command to the input stream
process = None
executable = '"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar nogui java'
while True:
    command=input()
    command=command.lower()
    if process is not None:
        if command==("start"):
            os.chdir(minecraft_dir)
            process = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            print("Server started.")
    else:
        server_command(command)
```

you can also pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` so you can also read it's output and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to read from it's error stream (if any)

As well instead of `process.stdin.write(cmd+"\n")` you could also use the `file` optional parameter of the print function, so this:

```
print(cmd, file=process.stdin)
```

Will write the data to process.stdin formatted in the same way that print normally does, like ending with newline for you unless passing `end=` to override it etc.

Answer (score 7):

Both of the above answers do not work in the environment I tried them in.

I think the best way is to use RCON, not sending keys to a window.

RCON is the protocol used by games to run commands.

Many python libraries support Minecraft RCON, and the default server.properties file has an option for RCON.

We will use the python module: [MCRON](https://pypi.org/project/mcrcon/).

Install it. It works for windows, mac, linux.

Type:

```
pip install mcrcon
```

Lets configure your server to allow RCON.

In server.properties, find the line 'enable-rcon' and make it look like this:

```
enable-rcon=true
```

Restart and stop your server.
Find the line 'rcon.password' and set it to any password you will remember.

You can leave the port default at 25575.

Now, open your terminal and type:

```
mcron localhost
```

Or your server ip.

You will be prompted to enter the password you set.
Then you can run commands and will get the result.

But we are doing this with python, not the PYPI MCRON scripts - so do this.

```
from mcrcon import MCRcon as r
with r('localhost', 'insertyourpasswordhere') as mcr:
    resp = mcr.command('/list')
print(resp) #there are 0/20 players online: - This will be different for you.
```

Comment: im mildy disappointed, as I spent lots of time and effort on this answer, for not even a comment a year later.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks for contributing. This seems like the intended way to do it.

Comment: looks simple! i'll try it.